# Is it possible to rename a USB flash drive and transfer files onto that drive with one script?

Tags: usb, batch, batch-file, usb-flash-drive, rename

I am using a batch (below) found elsewhere to facilitate moving the files onto the USB flash drives, but want to also rename the flash drive in the process. How would I incorporate the renaming portion in Win10? Most searches suggest using Powershell but I was hoping to wrap the whole process sup in one script.

Any suggestions or information to point me in the right direction is highly appreciated!

```
@echo off
cls
:start
set choice=
xcopy /e /y C:\Users\asimpson\Desktop\transfer\*.* E:
goto wait

:check
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo waiting
if exist E: (goto start) else goto check

:wait
timeout /t 1 /nobreak >nul
echo Waiting for removal
if exist E: (goto wait) else goto removed

:removed
echo removed
goto check
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The label command is what you're looking for.

Note that you have to run this as an administrator.

```
c:\>label /?
Creates, changes, or deletes the volume label of a disk.

LABEL [drive:][label]
LABEL [/MP] [volume] [label]

  drive:          Specifies the drive letter of a drive.
  label           Specifies the label of the volume.
  /MP             Specifies that the volume should be treated as a
                  mount point or volume name.
  volume          Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                  mount point, or volume name.  If volume name is specified,
                  the /MP flag is unnecessary.
```

And so:

```
C:\>label c: CeeDrive

C:\>dir c:
 Volume in drive C is CeeDrive
 Volume Serial Number is 7AAA-A01B
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactly what I was looking for.